# Transporter library

Tags: path, itmstransporter

I am using Personal learning edition
Whenever I select a transporter Type icon such as AGV and give it a path to follow, I don't get a picture following a path, instead getting a java error.

> Errors are: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: ..\3d\forklift.dae at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
> at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
> .......

Many thanks

I made a model and select a transporter type and select an icon for that. I am expecting that the selected icon such as AGV moves along the path.